# AVR assembler arithmetics - how to see the output

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

I am trying a lot of stuff with AVR, using Atmel Studios and simulator for ATmega2560. Now I am trying to understand some basic stuff in the assembler.
What I'm trying is really simple arithmetics but I am lost in how I can get an output to confirm that I am doing it right. This code is the most simple one add 2+2 and I am trying to use PORTB as output so when I step over it I should see PORTB 4 in the console down under, but I just step over and get no hint what is going on. Can someone point me out a good way to see the results of my arithmetic experiments?

```
ldi r17,0xFF
ldi r16,2
ldi r18,2
add r16,18
out DDRB,r17
out PORTB,r16 //was hoping to see 4 in console or somewhere

start:
      rjmp Start
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems to be okay, but maybe you made some copy-pastes/typos `add r16,r18`

[image]

Comment: Probably the OP needs a hint how to display the I/O window?

Comment: He  was adding 18 to r16 instead of r18, or pasted the wrong code here :)